# How to implement returning to top level menu?

Tags: bash

I have a complex menu driven program along the following lines:

```
echo "Navigate through the following choices when you get the #? prompt: "
options=("Action 1" "Action 2" ...)
select $opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Action 1")
            ./action1.sh 
            ;;
        "Action 2")
            ./action1.sh 
            ;;
        ...
    esac
done
```

(Think of it as a simple todo list application where you can add/delete/edit/view todo list items. So, adding, deleting, etc. are the actions)

Some of these `action`s are a bit long, so it is possible that halfway through the action, the user changes their mind and wishes to return to the main prompt to try out some other action.

My question is how to allow the user to return back to the main prompt? I was hoping for a simple keypress handler that would let the user jump to the top of `select`. Is it possible or are there other methods?

Comment: Does the scripts that implement the actions actually support early termination? I mean, that won't leave something in an indeterminate/broken state? Do the scripts run further commands that needs to be terminated for the user to get back?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, terminating the other scripts prematurely won't leave the system in any broken state.

Answer (score 0):

You could restart your main program.

```
 # User wants to return to main
 exec main.sh
```

This will remove your currently running script and replace it with `main.sh`.

Note that only the variables that are exported are available in the newly started `main.sh`.